# Interoperability of PHP, OpenSSL and C# regarding AES encryption

Tags: c#, php, openssl

Given a PHP script that encrypts a string with openssl_encrypt, I want to decrypt the output with openssl CLI and C#.
Although I can encrypt and decrypt the string in each programming language on its own with key and IV, I cannot decrypt the PHP output with openssl CLI and C#.

This is the PHP script:

```
<?php

function bad_crypt($string, $action = 'e') {
    if (empty($string)) {
        return "";
    }

    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $key = "3d13b07f244861f2d323d1734d773ce4bd079e2c17deb5695911e1387e0b579a";
    $iv = "d9ec53dadaf1e968"; // bad practice, but this is just a test

    echo "key:";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $key;
    echo "<br>";

    echo "iv:";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $iv;
    echo "<br>";

    if ($action == 'e') {
        $output = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv));
    } else if ($action == 'd') {
        $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    }

    return $output;
}

$info = "mysecret";
$encInfo = bad_crypt($info);

echo "encrypted:";
echo "<br>";
echo $encInfo;

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$t = bad_crypt($encInfo, "d");

echo "decrypted:";
echo "<br>";
echo $t;
?>
```

which gives the following output:

```
key:
3d13b07f244861f2d323d1734d773ce4bd079e2c17deb5695911e1387e0b579a
iv:
d9ec53dadaf1e968
encrypted:
QVBBaDcrdkRUdVFqZDV5cGFMNHJCdz09


key:
3d13b07f244861f2d323d1734d773ce4bd079e2c17deb5695911e1387e0b579a
iv:
d9ec53dadaf1e968
decrypted:
mysecret
```

I have tried numerous combinations of options for openssl; none did reproduce the PHP encryption result or decrypted it.

Example openssl encryption command:

`openssl.exe enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -K 3d13b07f244861f2d323d1734d773ce4bd079e2c17deb5695911e1387e0b579a -iv d9ec53dadaf1e968 -in mysecret.txt`

with `mysecret.txt` containing `mysecret` results in `plQ2hEAoywxUeFWniDszdQ==`.

Any help is appreciated.
Looking forward to a working openssl cli command and a C# program.

**Edit / Clarification:**
The PHP code is given and cannot be changed.
The goal is to find an equvalent openssl command and C# program.

Comment: I believe you are facing padding differences between PHP's openssl_encrypt and OpenSSL.

Comment: @Adi Maybe. However, I do not figure out how to solve this issue.

Comment: For AES-256-CBC you need a 32 bytes key and a 16 bytes IV. Key and IV in the PHP codes seem to be hex encoded. However, the hex decoding is missing. In addition, the length of the IV (assuming hex encoding) is not correct. In the OpenSSL statement, the hex encoded values must be specified with `-K` and `-iv`. Also, PHP/OpenSSL Base64 encodes/decodes *implicitly* by default.

Comment: Thank you @Topaco for your inputs. I have already specified `-K` and `-iv`. From your answer I assume I must Hex-**en**code  the PHP strings for key and iv for the openssl command?
So what are the resulting values? I have tried 3364313362303766323434383631663264333233643137333464373733636534 for `-K` and 64396563353364616461663165393638 for `-iv` but that seems not to be correct.

Comment: Are you still Base64 encoding/decoding twice in the PHP code?

Comment: Apart from the bugs: Be aware that it reduces security if a hex encoded value is simply ASCII encoded and used as key. A key is a random byte sequence of which each byte can have 256 different values (and not just 16).

Comment: @Topaco I am aware that the PHP code is bad, meaning not secure. But I have to deal with it. The code cannot be changed. The Base64 encoding/decoding in the PHP code is as it is. My goal is to find an equivalent openssl command.

Comment: Then you have to Base64 encode/decode twice in the OpenSSL statement.

Comment: E.g. encryption with 1st Base64 encoding: `openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -A -K 3364... -iv 6439... -in mysecret.txt -out encrypted.txt` and 2nd Base64 encoding `openssl enc -e -a -A -in encrypted.txt`

Comment: Or here in an online bash https://onlinegdb.com/mmc-gWinC

Comment: ...which matches the result from your PHP code: https://paiza.io/projects/ICoyn54LYBlouQSGSkS4sg

Comment: Thank you very much, @Topaco! Perfect! YMMD!